# How to read Text From a listbox after certain point in array?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, console

Bellow I have some code that takes a `RichTextBox1` text and places it in a list box. I do this to read the text line by line and when checking for this I put the text within an array so I can check both the text and spaces. This all works Correctly However when I type a command such as `'Print = Hello My Name is`' the console only outputs Hello and nothing else even though I want it to print 'Hello My Name is'. So the problem is printing after the 3rd space

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
///RTB = rich Text Box

        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(RTB.Lines)
            For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim teststring As String = ListBox1.Items.Item(i)
            Dim testarray() As String = Split(teststring)

            If testarray(0) = "Print" Then
                If testarray(1) = "=" Then
                    Console.WriteLine(testarray(2))
                End If
            End If
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you just split by " ", so this is expected behavior. It only did what you told it to do.

You probably need to look into using regex to properly implement this kind of parsing.

This should get you started:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim s As String = "Print = Hello My Name is"
    Dim re As New Regex("(.*)=(.*)")

    Dim m As Match = re.Match(s)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(2).Value.Trim) '=Console.WriteLine(testarray(2))
  End Sub
End Module
```

As mentioned in the comment, the last line should print what you expect.

Comment: Thanks so much the code provided worked great with a few adaptations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling `Split` with no additional parameters, so, by default, it splits on spaces.  That means that your `testarray` will contain one element per word in the line.  To fix it, you could just split on the `=` character, like this:

```
If testString.Contains("=") Then
    Dim testArray() As String = teststring.Split("="c)
    If testArray(0) = "Print" Then
        Console.WriteLine(testArray(1))
    End If
End If
```

Also, the above code will only work properly if there are no spaces between the word "Print" and the equal sign.  To handle white-space between those, you need to trim the values after splitting them.

However, that will only work properly if the string to print does not contain an equal sign.  If that is a concern, you could do something like this:

```
Dim index As Integer = testString.IndexOf("=")
If index >= 0 Then
    If testString.Substring(0, index).TrimEnd() = "Print" Then
        Console.WriteLine(testString.Substring(index + 1).TrimStart())
    End If
End If
```

Normally, I'd recommend looking into using RegEx for something like this, but since, I gather, you are a beginner, that's probably a bit to advanced for you right now.

I should also mention that you don't need to use a `ListBox` to hold the lines.  You can just hold them in an array in memory.  Or, better yet, you can just loop through the return value of the rich text box's `Lines` property directly, rather than storing it in a variable at all, for instance:

```
For Each line As String In RTB.Lines
    Dim index As Integer = line.IndexOf("=")
    If index >= 0 Then
        If line.Substring(0, index).TrimEnd() = "Print" Then
            Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(index + 1).TrimStart())
        End If
    End If        
Next
```